After opening a new file the console does not seem to respond to the written code anymore?
Just starting out on learning Python. I've written some very basic codes on Spyder to practice. all of which ran without a problem or were marked red if an error in the code was detected. However, now I can't get the code to run whatsoever. What could be the problem here?
I had three different files open on the same time. I'd assume that the console would run the code that ís on the file which is being edited and not the files which are open as tabs. The only code I got in the console was from the files which I had open in tabs but was not actively editing anymore. But even though I closed all of them, the code of the new file did not get run.

Now that I shut and reopened Spyder, there's a file called temp-py shown which has some of my previous practice code on it. Could this file type maybe prevent or interrupt new files from running?

This is one of the rare times I think a screenshot of the editor would help. I suspect you're inside the python interpreter

The quick fix to that problem would be typing exit() , entering that and then trying again
